# Rock Paper Scissors program while loop

Tags: java

I coded an RPS program that works fine. My only problem is that it has to keep going forever until the user's input is "stop". I tried to do this with a while loop but I get a weird output that keeps asking for the user's input. I understand that one of my mistakes is that I need to prompt for the input inside the while loop but then how would I intiate the while loop to begin with.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Navairps
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random();
      play(input,rand);
   }
   //outputs the description and rules of the game
   public static void description()
   {
      System.out.println("Using this app you can play Rock-Paper-Scissors game against the computer. When played between");
      System.out.println("two people, each person picks one of the three options at the same time, and the winner");
      System.out.println("Is determined. The program should randomly choose one of the three options, then prompt for the");
      System.out.println("user's selection. At that point, the program reveals both choices and print a");
      System.out.println("Statement indicating if the user won, the computer won, or if it was a tie. Continue playing until the");
      System.out.println("user choose to stop. Then print the total number of the games played, total wins, total losses, and");
      System.out.println("total ties.");
      System.out.println("Ready, Set, Go\n");
      System.out.println("your choices");
      System.out.println("\tRock");
      System.out.println("\tPaper");
      System.out.println("\tScissors");
      System.out.println("\tstop");
   }
   //generates a random number (0-2) for the computer selection
   public static String computerRandom(Random rand)
   {
      int computer = rand.nextInt(3);
      String computerInput=("");
      switch (computer)
      {
         case 0: computerInput = "rock";
                 break;
         case 1: computerInput = "paper";
                 break;
         case 2: computerInput = "scissors";
                 break;
      }
      return computerInput;   
   }
   //gets the users choice via Scanner class and returns it, must check if input is valid
   public static String userInput(Scanner input)
   {
      System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
      String choice = input.nextLine();
      choice = choice.toUpperCase();
      return choice;     
   }
   //initiates the game, allows user to keep playing, keeps track of score
   public static void play(Scanner input, Random rand)
   {
      description();
      int wins=0;
      int draws=0;
      int losses=0;
      String choice = userInput(input);
      while (!choice.equals("STOP"));
      {
         String computerChoice = computerRandom(rand);
         System.out.println("Computer selected: " + computerChoice);
         computerChoice = computerChoice.toUpperCase();
         System.out.println("You selected: " + choice);
         if (computerChoice.equals(choice))
         {
            System.out.println("There is a tie");
            draws++;
            //add 1 to ties
         } 
         if (computerChoice.equals("ROCK") && choice.equals("SCISSORS"))
         {
            System.out.println("Oh No, you lost");
            losses++;
            //add 1 to losses
         }
         if (computerChoice.equals("SCISSORS") && choice.equals("ROCK"))
         {
            System.out.println("Hurray! You won");
            wins++;
            //add 1 to wins
         } 
         if (computerChoice.equals("PAPER") && choice.equals("ROCK"))
         {
            System.out.println("Oh No, you lost");
            losses++;
            //add 1 to losses
         } 
         if (computerChoice.equals("ROCK") && choice.equals("PAPER"))
         {
            System.out.println("Hurry! You won");
            wins++;
            //add 1 to wins
         } 
         if (computerChoice.equals("PAPER") && choice.equals("SCISSORS"))
         {
            System.out.println("Hurry! You won");
            wins++;
            //add 1 to wins
         } 
         if (computerChoice.equals("SCISSORS") && choice.equals("PAPER"))
         {
            System.out.println("Oh No, you lost");
            losses++;
            //add 1 to losses
         } 
      }
      /*if (choice.equals("stop"));
      {
         System.out.print("come back soon");
      }*/
   }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a `do ... while` loop.

Comment: If you want debugging help, you **have to** post your code. Also, do not spam tags - Java and JavaScript are almost entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook example of a `do{} while()` loop. Instead of using the while loop, change your code as follows:

```
public static void play(Scanner input, Random rand)
   {  
      ...
      do {
         choice = userInput(input);
         String computerChoice = computerRandom(rand);
         ...
      } while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"));
   }
```

This will solve your problem.

However, when you give the STOP command, you probably don't want the game to compute a random value any more, so you probably want an extra *if*-condition to prevent the computer from playing further:

```
if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")){
         String computerChoice = computerRandom(rand);
         System.out.println("Computer selected: " + computerChoice);
         ...
}
```

Remark that instead of using an *if*-statement, you could also use `break` to break out of the loop: `if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) break;`

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the while loop at the on load of the app/ program then use a `break;` to end the while loop under a if condition

Comment: Are you suggesting `while(true)`?

Comment: Yes  onload method{ while (truevariable){//loopcode     if (){   break;}  };};

Comment: I don't understand your comment *"`while (truevariable)`"*: if you use a variable then why would you also need a `break`?

Comment: You could do both

Comment: Depends on how to want to end the loop but they both will work

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues here

1. the stop command is `STOP` and not lower-case `stop`
2. `choice = userInput(input)` is only set once outside the loop

As stated previously in some comments, `do {} while()` is the way to go.

Note you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()`, so you do not need to convert everything to uppercase.